# Parse data from website using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

i'm creating an android app which is gathering data from www.zamboangatoday.ph, get all the news titles or headers. but i can retrieve only one item can someone check my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



            try{

                outputTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                //Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html,"http://www.zamboangatoday.ph");
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.zamboangatoday.ph/").get();
                //Elements tag = doc.select(".even h4 a");

                Iterator<Element> iter = doc.select("li.even h4 a").iterator();
                //List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
                while(iter.hasNext())
                {
                    Element element = iter.next();

                    outputTextView.setText(element.text());

                }

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not shure what component `outputTextView` is, but with this code:

```
outputTextView.setText(element.text());
```

you'll set the text, and **overwrite** it with each iteration. So after your loop there will be only the last elements text. If possible use something like `outputTextView.append(element.text());` - else use a `StringBuilder` and set the text after the loop.

---

```
outputTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
//Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html,"http://www.zamboangatoday.ph");
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.zamboangatoday.ph/").get();
//Elements tag = doc.select(".even h4 a");

Iterator<Element> iter = doc.select("li.even h4 a").iterator();
//List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
while(iter.hasNext())
{
    Element element = iter.next();

    /*
     * Append the text - don't overwrite it
     * Node: Maybe you have to add a new line ('\n').
     */
    outputTextView.append(element.text()); 

}
```

Comment: ok i get this done. can someone help me how to implement it using listviews.

Comment: if this solved your problem, you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) this answer.

Comment: Relating to listviews: if theres no question existing, feel free to open an new one for this.